# php-fpm + nginx server configuration

Tags: php, nginx, server-configuration

I get `POST Content-Length of 70116320 bytes exceeds the limit of 52428800 bytes` on my nginx error.log 
so I changed `post_max_size` from 8M to 128M (php.ini) but I get `502 Bad Gateway` on my web apps. 
When I check `php-fpm.log`, I get `[pool www] child 3328525 exited with code 70 after 319.595594 seconds from start`. 
Then, I tried to change `max_execution_time` (www.pool)  from 300 to 600, but it didn't work. 
Then I tried to change the `post_max_size` from 128M to 50M and it works (there's no 502 Bad Gateway). 
But, I need to change `post_max_size` more than 50M (I wish it can be 128M, because the data is large) with no 502 Bad Gateway.

My questions is:

1. When I changed `post_max_size` parameter, then what others parameter should be adjust to get best result?
2. What should I do when I want to do php-fpm + nginx configuration
   tuning?
3. What is the maximum size of those parameters?

Thank you, maybe you guys can help my case..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change BOTH the max_execution_time and post_max_size to suit your needs

Reasons:

1. Posting data to server requires time. If you have changed the post_max_size to a large value and then send large amount of data (say uploading a big file) by post, it requires longer time. (hence need to adjust max_execution_time)
2. There is no such thing as max_execution_size

Make sure your system resources can handle it (without adverse effect) on what you have set

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your suggestion.. sorry for miss typing, yes I mean max_execution_time. For example, if I put 128M to post_max_size.. is there any certain formula about the suitable ideal value for max_execution_time? so that it can be handling the big size of uploading file by post

Comment: One of my clients who needs to upload large files has set the max_execution_time to 1800 (that's already 30 minutes). The server is a standard server and it works without undue problems. I think you may try a similar figure. (make sure you restart the server after amending the php.ini)